# Assessing if points exhibit spatial clustering (using R)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distribution, spatial, hierarchical-clustering

This is a bit of a theoretical and practical question at the same time.
I have a df containing x, y, z coordinates of a list of points. These points are dots on a 3D surface generated by image segmentation.
The question I am trying to address is if these points are randomly distributed on this surface or if they exhibit some clustering. I'm testing this in R.

The first method I am using is kmeans. I ask the computer to determine the best (if any) number of groups these data can be made to fit into. 
I am using this piece of code. It tests 30 different indices (various methods) and outputs the best number of clusters

```
library("NbClust")
nb <- NbClust(df, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2,
          max.nc = 10, method = "kmeans")
library("factoextra")
fviz_nbclust(nb)
```

This code comes from 
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/29-cluster-validation-essentials/96-determining-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-3-must-know-methods/

I get a certain number of clusters, which I guess is an indication of clustering in the first place.
However, I would like to calculate a metric out of it? Suggestions on how to?

In addition I am also checking for clustering via histograms.

```
     df_mat <- df %>% as.matrix()
     dist_df <- dist(df_mat)
     hist(dist_df)
```

You would expect multiple peaks for clustering, one single peak for more or less random distributions perhaps.

Another approach I am trying is hierarchical clustering

```
 my_hclustdf <- hclust(dist_df)
 plot(my_hclustdf)
```

However, the output, a dendogram, itself does not tell me much.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> randomly distributed on this surface or if they exhibit some clustering

The problem is that this is too vague. What is 'randomly distributed' and what is 'some clustering'?

There exist some tools to test such cases. For example Hopkins statistic can be used to test if the distribution appears to be uniform random. But the absence of a uniform random distribution does not imply there are clusters - it's just not uniform. Similar problems hold for k-means: just because some heuristic tells you to use k=3 does not at all prove there are three clusters. It may also suggest this even in uniform random data. If you tell k-means to find k clusters, then it will find k "clusters". Even on uniform random data.

What you would probably want is to find multiple - separate - *density modes*.